# SQL Server Management Studio: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0'

Tags: ssms

I've had this problem for a while and can't find anyone with the exact same issue.

I get the error when trying to select top 1000 rows.

I checked in the PublicAssemblies and it is not there. the lowest version there is 9.0. And I can't find a copy anywhere else.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of SSMS are you on?

Comment: v18.4 on the startup screen

Comment: 15.0.18206.0 in the about